# Shortcuts for vmlite android?

Tags: android, keyboard-shortcuts, vmlite

I'm using [vmlite android](http://www.vmlite.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=69&Itemid=178) to develop android applications.

I wonder if there is any shortcut available, e.g. `back` / `home`. I need them because there are some applications which don't provide `back` or `quit` buttons, if I run them, I don't get a way to quit.

---

**UPDATE**

There is no navigation bar in the bottom, see my screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Home key
Esc key
Right mouse click

Also you should see navigation bar at bottom with Back, Home, Recent Apps special keys

Comment: `Esc` key works as `back`. `Home` doesn't work, `right click` is the same as left click? I just uploaded a screenshot, you can see there is no navigation bar at bottom. Thank you for `esc`, I really need it!